# How to align bars to function line in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking to create a bar graph in mat plot lib where the top left corner of the bar touches the function line as seen in the below image. How would I change the code below to achieve this. For sake of this example lets say that the plt.plot() line is the function line.

```py
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xVal = []
yVal = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    xVal.append((i/10))
    yVal.append((2*i*math.pi)/10)

plt.bar(x=xVal, height=yVal, width=0.1, align='edge')
plt.plot(xVal, yVal)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It depends on how the current result is different from the desired result. Can you explain that?

Comment: Hi so the image I posted is what I want it to look like, currently in my program the line passes the the center of the bar and so looks invisible. Im not looking to mutate the math to get it to fit but rather if there is a mat plot lib function to help with this

Comment: Thanks, I can do that already but looking for a coding way to do it, not a math one

Comment: Did you read https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html?

Comment: Will look through it, thanks

Comment: This absolutely is a math problem.  A bar chart BY DESIGN has the bar centered on its value.  If you don't want that, then shift the X axis of the bar values so the bars are centered half a bar width to the right.

Comment: Since you are already using `align='edge'`, it should do what you are asking for. Maybe you are accidentally looking at the result of an earlier version of the code or something like that. You could verify that you are actually getting different results when changing between `align='edge'` and `align='center'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your x-coordinate by 0.1.

For example:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xVal = []
yVal = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    xVal.append((i/10))
    yVal.append((2*i*math.pi)/10)

plt.plot(xVal, yVal)
x = lambda a: a + 0.1
xVal = [x(i) for i in xVal]
plt.bar(x=xVal, height=yVal, width=-0.1, align='edge')
plt.show()
```